# How to call function from another plugin?

Tags: plugin-development, advanced-custom-fields

I am using the [Advanced Custom Fields plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/) and want to read the value of the custom fields. For dropdown and text fields, this is straightforward as the value is kept in plain text, so the `get_post_custom_values` functions works.

For multi-select field, however, ACF keeps data like this:

```
a:1:{i:0;s:3:"Value2";}
```

So the sensible thing to do is to use the `get_value` function from ACF to read the value and parse it into objects.

In the ACF plugin, the first line does:

```
$acf = new Acf();
```

So I assumed I could just use the $acf variable in my plugin and do:

```
$afc->get_value ($post_id, $key);
```

but received error with

```
PHP Notice:  Undefined variable
```

I am new to php development so I might not have understood the scoping rule correctly.  So, what's the right way to do this and what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The multi-select field you referenced appears to be stored in [PHP serialized format](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php), which is used for "storing or passing PHP values around without losing their type and structure".

To unserialize a custom field value you need to use the [unserialize()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php) function:

```
$multi_select_field = unserialize( get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'custom_field_key', true ) );
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I will try out this approach.  However, I would still like to know how I can call a function from another plugin.